# Created a new user in Ubuntu server but it wont show in the terminal

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, apache2, sudo

When I installed the Ubuntu server I had to make a user and name my computer. When I login the terminal shows `gery@server:~$`. After a while I installed vsftpd and LAMP services to my server. So I made a user called ftpuser for future webpage uploads. I made it's home directory `/var/www/html` where an Apache HTTP server reads html files and displays them in the browser. My problem is that when I log in with the ftpuser I only get this symbol `$`. I made ftpuser sudo and I `chmod 755` the html directory and all it's files. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Probably because you used a pre-existing directory for the user's home, files from `/etc/skel` (including the default `.bashrc`, which is where customizations for the prompt are made) were not copied during account creation. Either that, or you set the user's login shell to something other than bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the `/etc/passwd` file and found out that my ftpuser uses a different shell than my other one.

```
gery:x:1000:1000:Tolnai Gergely:/home/gery:/bin/bash
ftpuser:x:1001:1001::/var/www/html:/bin/sh
```

Apparently there are two commands to create a new user. I used `useradd ftpuser` which is the wrong one. It uses the `/bin/sh` shell which gives me this symbol `$`. I deleted the user with `userdel ftpuser` and recreated with the right command `adduser ftpuser` wich uses the `/bin/bash` shell. Now im geting the `ftpuser@server:~$` format in the terminal.